# Datagrid not firing AddingNewItem or InitializingNewItem event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid binded to observablecollection. By clicking button new row is added, and i wana to start editing new row as soon as its added. For this purpose i wana use **AddingNewItem** or **InitializingNewItem** events, because i think that i can acces newly added row in this event and call BeginInit on it (or something similar)

But in code like bellow, i cannot make events work. When i add new item, events are not fired. Am i missing something?

```
<DataGrid Margin="5"
          AddingNewItem="enumerationsDataGrid_AddingNewItem"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          InitializingNewItem="enumerationsDataGrid_InitializingNewItem"
          ItemsSource="{Binding TypesAllAvailable}"
          RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed">

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Expander x:Name="rowDetailsExpander"
                              Cursor="Hand"
                              IsExpanded="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Mode=TwoWay, Path=DetailsVisibility, Converter={StaticResource visToBoolConverter}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="0.7*"
                            Binding="{Binding TypeName}"
                            Header="Name" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="0.2*"
                            Binding="{Binding Enumerations.Count}"
                            Header="Enums"
                            IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="0.7*"
                            Binding="{Binding Parent.Name}"
                            Header="Scope"
                            IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <DataGrid x:Name="enumerationsDataGrid"
                          Margin="5 0 5 5"
                          AddingNewItem="enumerationsDataGrid_AddingNewItem"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Enumerations}"
                          SizeChanged="enumerationsDataGrid_SizeChanged">
                    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridRow}"
                               TargetType="DataGridRow">

                            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext}" />
                            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ContextMenu>

                                        <MenuItem Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.RemoveEnumerationValueCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                                  Header="_Delete enumeration" />
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"
                                            Header="Enumerations" />

                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
                <TextBlock Margin="5 0 5 5"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Foreground="Black"
                           Text="No enumerations found."
                           Visibility="{Binding Items.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource bool2VisibilityConverter}, ElementName=enumerationsDataGrid}" />
                <Button Width="110"
                        Margin="5 0 0 5"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Command="{Binding AddEnumerationValueCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                        Content="New enumeration" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridRow}"
               TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <!--<Setter Property="DetailsVisibility" Value="{Binding ElementName=rowDetailsExpander}, Path=IsExpanded}" /> -->
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext}" />
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Command="{Binding Parent.RemoveStateTypeCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                  Header="_Delete state" />
                        <!--  Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.DeleteObjectiveStateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"  -->
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Events are in same UserControl and breakpoint not hitting...

```
private void enumerationsDataGrid_AddingNewItem(object sender, AddingNewItemEventArgs e)
{

}

private void enumerationsDataGrid_InitializingNewItem(object sender, InitializingNewItemEventArgs e)
{

}
```

**EDIT**
Im using DataGrid component which should have event **AddingNewItem** and **InitializingNewItem**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.addingnewitem?view=netframework-4.7.2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.initializingnewitem?view=netframework-4.7.2

When i initialize datagrid as in example above, bind it on Observable collection and add item to bound collection, none of this events are fired. And im curious why those events are not fired?

Binding seems okay, because item is correctly added into datagrid.

**EDIT2**

I know about notify events and observable collections, but watching this i can access only ViewModel class. But what i wana is, that when user add new row, that row will switch into Edit mode and user can write into its cells. Instead of double clicking on it.

So thats why im trying to use those two events. BEcause when i have reference on cell, i can call BeginEdit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.beginedit?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Please clarify your **specific problem** or **add additional details** to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Hille i added more information to question, but cant understand what was here missing. Im using WPF component and cant understand why it isnt firing events from documentation

Comment: Just some important details like what type your binding, is it a list, a class, a table

Comment: IMHO you should watch the bound collection instead of working on events raised by your DataGrid

Comment: @IlVic i can watch collection, but then there is no reference to added row in datagrid, and why are there those events then?

Comment: You can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.collectionchanged?view=netframework-4.8) about a useful collection event. You can find also useful info [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level)

Comment: @IlVic i know about INotifyProperty changed, event about observable collection. It alls notify me about changed object on ViewModel, but i need to access new created DatagridRow to call BeginEdit on it (or something similar) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.beginedit?view=netframework-4.7.2